# Frame numbering in different lectures (custom Beamer template)

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, templates

I'm trying to define a custom template and was satisfied with a *frametitle* template which displays frame numbering using

```
\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber
```

It worked perfectly fine **until** I decided to split my presentation into different lectures using `\includeonlylecture` and `\lecture`.
Indeed, now the frame numbering displays the frame number from the complete presentation (even if other frames, from other lectures, are not available on the pdf).

I tried several modifications of the code and online search, but all I can do is replace the frame numbers by the page numbers which is *quite ok* except when there are overlays.

Is there any command to report the current frame number of the **lecture** rather than the frame number as computed from the complete presentation?

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{titleframecolor}{RGB}{52,82,122}
\colorlet{frametitlefc}{white}

\setbeamerfont{framenumber}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{x}[1][]
{
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle}[titleframecolor]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2cm);
      \fill[titleframecolor] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2cm);%
      {\node[anchor=west,frametitlefc,align=left] (frametitle) at ({1cm-1.5ex,0.6cm}){\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\begin{tabular}{l}\insertframetitle\end{tabular}};}%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %%%%% PART THAT MUST BE FIXED
      \node [anchor=south east,white] at (\the\paperwidth,-.5ex) {\usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber};
      %% Alternative
      %\node [anchor=south east,white] at (\the\paperwidth,-.5ex) {\usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertpagenumber~/~\insertpresentationendpage};
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\includeonlylecture{l2}


\begin{document}
\lecture{lecture 1}{l1}
\begin{frame}{Lecure 1 Slide 1 -- Should be page 1/1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\lecture{lecture 2}{l2}
\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 1 -- Should be page 1/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item
        \item<2-> item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 2 -- Should be page 2/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item
        \item<2-> item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 3 -- Should be page 3/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\lecture{lecture 3}{l3}
\begin{frame}{Lecture 3 slide 1 -- Should be page 1/1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Warm regards.

Comment: Are you using overlays and/or `\pause` in your slides?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not using `\pause` but uses overlays as seen in the MWE

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed these overlays in your code. So the easy route via pageref is ruled out. I think your best bet is using this fix https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1987#a2230 for xcntperchap to count the frames in each lecture

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with `\includeonlylecture`, but you could use it to get per lecture numbering in your complete presentation and then split the resulting pdf into individual lectures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{titleframecolor}{RGB}{52,82,122}
\colorlet{frametitlefc}{white}

\setbeamerfont{framenumber}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{lecturestartframe}
\newcounter{lectureendframe}
\newcounter{nextlecturenum}
\newcounter{frameinlecture}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{x}[1][]
{
  \setcounterref{lecturestartframe}{lec\thelecture}
  \setcounter{nextlecturenum}{\thelecture}
  \addtocounter{nextlecturenum}{1}
  \setcounterref{lectureendframe}{lec\thenextlecturenum} 
  \addtocounter{lectureendframe}{-\thelecturestartframe}
  \setcounter{frameinlecture}{\theframenumber}
  \addtocounter{frameinlecture}{-\thelecturestartframe}
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle}[titleframecolor]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2cm);
      \fill[titleframecolor] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2cm);%
      {\node[anchor=west,frametitlefc,align=left] (frametitle) at ({1cm-1.5ex,0.6cm}){\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\begin{tabular}{l}\insertframetitle \end{tabular}};}%
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %%%%% PART THAT MUST BE FIXED
      \node [anchor=south east,white] at (\the\paperwidth,-.5ex) {\usebeamerfont{framenumber}\theframeinlecture~/~\thelectureendframe~};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\AtBeginLecture{
\begin{frame}[label=lec\thelecture,noframenumbering,plain]
  \begingroup
    \centering
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}Lecture~\insertlecturenumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertlecture\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
\end{frame}
}


\AtEndDocument{\lecture{foo}{foo}}



\begin{document}
\lecture{Foo}{l1}
\begin{frame}{Lecure 1 Slide 1 -- Should be page 1/1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\lecture{Bar}{l2}
\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 1 -- Should be page 1/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item
        \item<2-> item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 2 -- Should be page 2/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> item
        \item<2-> item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lecture 2 slide 3 -- Should be page 3/3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\lecture{Baz}{ll}
\begin{frame}[label=foo]{Lecture 3 slide 1 -- Should be page 1/1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \item item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```